# How exactly does one automate internet explorer tests with selenium grid?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-iedriver

I have a GoCD server that I plan on running my selenium test suite on. This machine is a Linux machine.  So.. I set up selenium on a windows machine. The key problem I am having is that when running as a service, or a scheduled task, the selenium hub does not launch IE.

If I remote desktop into the machine, run the jar manually from command line, the browser launches in my RDP session and the tests all pass. If I install it as a service (With permissions to interact with the desktop!) the driver appears to run, but the content never loads.

So if you have an answer, please remember:

- The grid works for all browsers with an interactive desktop session open.
- Without an interactive desktop session, Chrome and Firefox tests still pass (in headless mode).
- I am using *no* selenium nodes, I am only using the standalone jar (not running as hub or node, just running the tests standalone.
- I am using version 3.14 of both selenium standalone and IEDriverServer.exe

I know that tons of people do automated IE tests with selenium, but how do they do it with Hub on windows?

I've tried literally every options setting I can see to try to phinigel a way to get it to work, but it's just not having it.

I also tried running as a scheduled task rather than a service, no dice there either.

This is the precise error the IETests are presenting:

```
Oct 09, 2018 1:15:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for value to contain "sign-in.host.com". Current value: "null" (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:283)
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials

Comment: There are too many permutations to enumerate them here. I'm going to try the powershell solution. The key problem seems to be that the IE browser is simply not launching when running as a service. I'm going to run it from the desktop and try the RDP hack to keep the windows session open. This will give IE the desktop it needs, and hopefully will let the driver server work properly.

Before going through what I've tried, if you are running hub as a service and automating IE tests, I'm interested to know if it just worked for you, or if it didn't, what you had to overcome to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have issues with IE selenium tests on a VM in azure. What i noticed was that while RDP to the machine everything worked fine but when i closed the session all tests failed.
What i ended up doing was leaving a logged in console session after every RDP closing.
After adding a trigger on session log off i run a powershell script with the following:

```
Tscon 1 /dest:console
```

This keeps an active desktop session and my tests on IE pass.

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot today, wish me luck